# Deploy a web app developed for Heroku to Azure

Tags: java, azure, heroku

I have a web app that was developed for the Heroku platform, but lately it has been failing due to resources. I want to test it on Azure but I have no idea how to deploy a web application there because it is my first time.

This is how my app looks:

[image]

And this is the Procfile file:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: App Service is probably a good start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-linux

Comment: I tried it but the example has a totally different structure